# SQL Server date function does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a project in which I have a database of a hotel. There are three tables named `room, hotel, booking`. I want to calculate the total revenue of today from all hotels. For that purpose I have the following query but it outputs nothing except `Null`.

```
SELECT 
    sum(price) TODAY_INCOME 
FROM 
    room
WHERE  
    roomNo IN (SELECT roomNo 
               FROM booking1
               WHERE datefrom1 <= GETDATE() AND dateTo1 >= GETDATE() 
                 AND hotelNo = (SELECT hotelNo FROM hotel
                                WHERE hotelName = 'avari'));
```

Any type of help would be appreciated.Following is the link to my tables .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZqO4.png

Comment: PLease show sample data to demonstrate that the query *should* return a non-NULL value.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because GetDate() returns a datetime, complete with timestamp.  So if you do `dateTo1 >= GETDATE()`, you are really saying `where dateTo1 >= '01/08/2014 11:44am'`, for example.  '01/08/2014 11:44 am' is greater than a date of '1/8/2014' because the time portion will default to midnight.

change your query to:

```
SELECT sum(price)  TODAY_INCOME from room
where roomNo IN(select roomNo from booking1
WHERE datefrom1 <= CAST(GETDATE() as date) AND dateTo1 >= cast( GETDATE() as date) AND
hotelNo =(select hotelNo from hotel
where hotelName = 'avari'));
```

Comment: using US-formatted dates.  they would turn into '2014-01-08 11:44 am' in the database